# Div flickers when using .scrollTop()

Tags: jquery

Im using jQuery to add a class to my header to make it fixed at the top of the window, after scrolling 300 pixels. However the sticky header appears but with a lot of flickering.

Seems the the same on every browser I try.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 300) {
        jQuery('.mkd-page-header').addClass('fixed-header');

    } else {
        jQuery('.mkd-page-header ').removeClass('fixed-header');
    }
});
```

Example: http://waysidecamping.madebyidm.co.uk/dev/

I've seen lots of questions similar to this but no answers have worked for me.

Comment: Use [`position:sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: @freedomn-m That didn't work

Comment: A quick look at your site and `position:sticky` should be ideal - add it to .mkd-page-header and remove your js - it might not be identical (no shading) but you could easily add the shading when it's not scrolled.  Your site is *exactly* what position:sticky was designed for.

Comment: Having said that, please read: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) - we can't/shouldn't debug your site directly.  To make the question an SO question, please add a [mcve] within the question - with just enough code to demonstrate the issue within the question.